# exception error after adding OnError

Tags: javascript, syntax, onerror

Hope someone can help.

I have a java script that creates a number of images within my html page. But if the image is missing (not found) i would like to display a default image (none.png). So using the onerror method above i have changed the working line below

from

```
aelem.innerHTML += "<img src='/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/" + itab + ".png' alt=" + TabNode.text + " />";
```

to

```
  aelem.innerHTML += "<img src='/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/" + itab + ".png' alt=" + TabNode.text + " onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/none.png';" />";
```

But my script now fails and says

Line 88.. (line above)
char 180 (which i think is single quote  ' )
expected ";"

Please could you help

Thanks

S

Comment: You shouldn't really be using `onX` attributes, at least not this way. It's not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape all `inner` double quotes with backslash:

```
aelem.innerHTML += "<img src=\"/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/" + itab + ".png\" alt=\"" + TabNode.text + "\" onerror=\"this.onerror=null;this.src='/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/none.png';\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it as follows

```
aelem.innerHTML += "<img src='/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/" + itab + ".png' alt=" + TabNode.text + " onerror='this.onerror=null;this.src=\'/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/none.png\';' />";
```

The way you are writing is not a good option. Always prefer to use functions instead of writing inline functions.

You could use the following

```
aelem.innerHTML += "<img src='/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/" + itab + ".png' alt=" + TabNode.text + " onerror='ChangeSource(this)' />";
```

Then create a new function

```
function ChangeSource(self) {
    self.onerror=null;
    self.src='/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/none.png';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more careful when using quotes inside quotes. Let's split your string concatenation on plus signs:

```
aelem.innerHTML += "<img src='/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/" +
 itab +
 ".png' alt=" +
 TabNode.text +
 " onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/AjaxZfc/ViewClient.aspx?public=only&name=Extensions/row/none.png';" />";
```

The problem is in the last line, you want to write onerror="something" but you have the whole image html code in double quotes already, so it's not interpreted correctly (the whole this.onerror... part is not treated as a string - I think you can see it easily when you look on how Stackoverflow colors your code).

In this example you can't easily change onerror=".." to onerror='..' because inside onerrror statement you also have to use single quotes in src attribute. One way to solve this problem is to escape some quote marks with backslashes.